# Show that the set {${\alpha \in F_{5^6} | F_5(\alpha)=F_{5^6} }$} contains 15480 elements

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

**Question:**  Show that the set {${\alpha \in F_{5^6} | F_5(\alpha)=F_{5^6} }$} contains $15480$ elements

Since this number is so large, I think there is some trick to get the answer.

Also $15480$ is quite near to $5^6$, since $5^6$-15480=145

Would these 145 elements , $\alpha$, be extended roots?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Consider the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ - if it has degree $<6$, then the field $F_5({\alpha})$ can't be $F_{5^6}$ (consider their dimensions as vector spaces over $F_5$). So it just comes down to counting such elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb F_{5^6}$ contains exactly one(!) subfield isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{5^3}$ and one isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{5^2}$, and they intersect in $\Bbb F_5$. As every proper subfield must be contained in one of these subfields, we conclude that $\Bbb F_{5}(\alpha)\ne \Bbb F_{5^6}$ iff $\alpha\in\Bbb F_{5^3}\cup \Bbb F_{5^2}$. Hence there are $|\Bbb F_{5^3}|+|\Bbb F_{5^2}|-|\Bbb F_{5^3}\cap\Bbb F_{5^2}|=5^3+5^2-5=145$ "bad" $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Are there any books/resources you can recommend so I can explore this idea further?